# to give a border for current page item

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to give a `border-bottom:2px` for current page. And also a pseudo class in between the menu item but it takes a long border width to the pseudo class. I want a border of current page small width as of a `a`

you can view the code in here

https://jsfiddle.net/1mtcs757/37/

Comment: I don´t understand your problem, please improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried on your jsfiddle. Just change the it that way:

```
#menu-menu-1 > li:before {
    position: absolute;
    top:  10px;
    right: -10px;
    content: ".";
    color: #000;
    /* padding-left: 10px; */
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu-menu-1 > li {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: bro it just worked. Thank you for this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Adding float:left to your css code will get your menu item border issue fixed.

```
.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```